# Is it possible to have multiple tab-bar controllers in an app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I would like to design an app that has a RootView with 4 buttons. Clicking on each button will load another view that has its own tab-bar controller. The tab-bar controller for each of the views is different.

If so, how do I go about implementing this?

Comment: Please do not tag UIKit questions as cocoa, as UIKit is not part of Cocoa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(ignoring the fact that this sounds like it violates the HIG) it should just be a matter of creating views in IB (likely in separate XIBs) and using them like you would anyway, except that you should set the view of File's Owner to the tab bar controller, just like you would for the top level tab bar controller.